# Where can I find a full reference of wxpython?

Tags: python, wxpython

Sorry the question may sound stupid, but I do need one. Right now I'm just adding a wx.TextCtrl in my GUI program, and I want to know what styles can I add (such as style=wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER), so I googled and end up reading this page: http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.TextCtrl-class.html. It must be the official one, but I wonder why there's NOT a list of available styles in this page. If the official reference doesn't provide enough info, where should I look at?

Although I finally found what I want in wxPython in Action ebook, just want to know if there's a BIG reference which includes almost all stuff. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use the Source, Luke.  What's stopping you from reading the source for the control?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I find Andrea Gavana's (creator of wx.lib.agw ) documentation more comprehensive then the offical wxpython docs.

http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/wxPython/APIMain.html

[Heres](http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/wxPython/Widgets/wx.TextCtrl.html) the page for the textCtrl which shows all the styles that are available.

Comment: Perfect! This documentation even lists the events that a widget generates.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the official docs are mostly auto-generated with Doxygen from the wxWidgets docs and the Python docstrings. To find styles and such, you'll need to go up the tree of widgets that the TextCtrl inherits from. As volting pointed out, Andrea also has a nice set of docs. Andrea also has docs for his library (agw) here:

http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/AGW_Docs/

Unfortunately, it appears to be down at the time of this writing. Another handy tool (again from Andrea) is the Windows Styles and Event Hunter, found here:

http://groups.google.com/group/wxPython-dev/browse_thread/thread/7c19477bbcad4ef4

I use it quite a bit. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

wxPython is a binding for wxWidgets. You may need to take a look [there](http://wxwidgets.org/).